# How to fix library dependence in a conan package

Tags: installation, qt5, conan

I am trying to install qt/5.14.2 with conan.
Using

```
qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable
```

I receive

```
ERROR: libpq/11.5: Error in package_info() method, line 211
    self.cpp_info.components["pq"].requires.append("zlib::zlib")
    AttributeError: 'Component' object has no attribute 'requires'
```

OK, there is a bug in libpq/11.5

I am trying to downgrade to

```
libpq/11.4@bincrafters/stable

ERROR: Conflict in qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable:
    'qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable' requires 'zlib/1.2.11' while 'libpq/11.4@bincrafters/stable' requires 'zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable'.
    To fix this conflict you need to override the package 'zlib' in your root package.
```

BTW:
Why is it not enough to require the correct version of the library, and requiring the same repository? (and require two different repositories in two different packages for the same dependence)

OK, I attempted

```
zlib/1.2.11@bincrafters/stable

WARN: libpq/11.4@bincrafters/stable: requirement zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable overridden by your conanfile to zlib/1.2.11@bincrafters/stable 
zlib/1.2.11@bincrafters/stable: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
zlib/1.2.11@bincrafters/stable: Trying with 'conan-center'...
zlib/1.2.11@bincrafters/stable: Trying with 'minres'...
zlib/1.2.11@bincrafters/stable: Trying with 'bincrafters'...
ERROR: Failed requirement 'zlib/1.2.11@bincrafters/stable' from 'libpq/11.4@bincrafters/stable'
ERROR: Unable to find 'zlib/1.2.11@bincrafters/stable' in remotes
```

Finally, I arrived at

```
libpq/11.4@bincrafters/stable
zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable
qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable
```

After this, it looks like it was oK:

```
Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable: Retrieving package 93c70de10405da9f2d5a1f42b8c299ca7af869d2 from remote 'bincrafters' 
Downloading conanmanifest.txt
Downloading conaninfo.txt
Downloading conan_package.tgz
....qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable: Package installed 93c70de10405da9f2d5a1f42b8c299ca7af869d2
qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable: Downloaded package revision 0
```

However, the install fails with

```
  CMake was unable to find Qt5, put qmake in your path or set
  QTDIR/QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE.
```

The package is downloaded, I see all components in the corresponding subdirectory in my home directory. However, unlike the other components, it is not installed, before CMake attempts to find it.

What do I wrong?

Comment: How did you link qt in your project?

Comment: Do you mean this line?
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS  Core Network Widgets Concurrent PrintSupport Test #LinguistTools
    REQUIRED)

Comment: In particular, but could you post all cmake file that you have please?

Comment: Try https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/versioning/introduction.html#dependencies-overriding

Answer (score 1):

In case of any strange behavior of conan, upgrade! For me, switch 1.24.0 -> 1.28.1 with configs clean up fixed the same problem with libpq/11.5